# Long Labels on Xaxis overlapping in Rgraph and decimals not displayed on yaxis

Tags: rgraph

X axis labels are person names each  20 character or less.They are overlapping how to correct it.Or is there a way to rotate it and display it vertically.

Also my y axis values are decimal like 0.56,0.777,0.045 etc,All these are displayed as 0 0 0.Cant we display them as decimals?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the text.angle option to rotate labels you could set it to 45, or 90. If you do you'll need to increase the size of your bottom gutter to accommodate it.

Alternatively you can prepend every other label with \r\n to spread them over two lines. Again, you'll probably need to increase the bottom gutter size.

To show your decimals you'll need to set the scale.decimals option to 3:

```
'scale.decimals': 3,
'labels': ['Frederick','\r\nJohnny','Lauren','\r\nJemima'],
// 'text.angle': 45
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir.Will try and tel u.